# Removing an Outlet

Tags: electrical

Beginning work on a house my kids inherited. Has a two wire electrical system. One of the outlets is burned out, causing no power two two bedrooms and a bathroom, except for 1 Outlet, which we believe is the first Outlet in that circuit.

I have mapped out the electrical cords in the Attic, so I'm looking for suggestions on how to remove that outlet from the circuit

Thanks
John

Comment: Why not replace the outlet? There are codes on the spacing of outlets removing one would probably violate the spacing requirement. If you install a gfci in that location it can now be a 3 prong just use one of the labels that says no equipment ground. The down stream outlets can be upgraded to 3 wire use the tag gfci protected and no equipment ground on any new 3 prong outlets fed from the gfci.

Comment: It really depends on how it is wired. Can you shoot some photos?  Also beware Ed Beal's warning about removing receptacles.  The rule is that appliances come with 6' cords, and receptacles must be placed so an appliance placed anywhere along a wall can reach a receptacle *without an extension cord*.   Your old house is grandfathered, and you don't have to *upgrade* it, but you can't *downgrade* it either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The effecting outlet is in a bedroom,  which we believe to be the second outlet in that circuit because one outlet in that bedroom works,  and nothing then the bad outlet,  and nothing after, affecting the small bathroom next to tat bedroom,  and the bedroom next to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The effecting outlet is in a bedroom,  which we believe to be the second outlet in that circuit because one outlet in that bedroom works,  and then the bad outlet,  and nothing after, affecting the small bathroom next to tat bedroom,  and the bedroom next to that. I'm a pretty handy guy,  working on my second reno, and I've been encouraged that I could handle the job of either rewiring or capping off tat outlet, but electricity is still a mystery,  one I have a healthy respect for. I can send the diagram I made of the circuit,  if that would help